# Неправильные значения input range при смене min и max

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Имеется 3 диапазона

1-100,
100-1000,
1000-10000

При установке 2 или 3 диапазона и возврате на 1, angular устанавливает неправильные значения.

$timeout помогает, но не всегда. Помогите побороть такое поведение.

```
function set(val) {
  val = parseInt(val);
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.val = val;
  }, 100)
}
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/v43h2y3m/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пофиксили в 1.5.9, там нет такой проблемы.